# Historical daylight savings in Windows

Tags: windows, delphi, timezone, dst

Is there a easy way in Windows (using Delphi, not .NET) to convert UTC times to a local time, with daylight saving adjustments.

Data goes back 12 years, so needs to take account of changes in DST start/end dates over that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny, a very similar question appeared yesterday on LinkedIn.

This is the answer I gave there:

> Time Zones are somewhat fluid,
>   especially when Daylight Saving Time
>   starts/finishes.
>
> This database (
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database
>   ) defines the time zones, and it
>   changes sometimes, so you need an
>   update mechanism as well.
>
> There is a .NET implementation that
>   you could wrap, or use as a base:
>   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/locale/zoneinfo_dotnet_api.aspx
>
> I'm not sure how up to date this
>   Delphi implementation is:
>   http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphitz/
>
> Let us know your final implementation.

**Edit:**
The project mentioned above seems empty, so I searched further and found the [Delphi TimeZone Database project](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-tzdb/) to be still active.

--jeroen

Comment: Thx, looks like the Delphi implementation will serve as a basis. Was hoping I wouldn't have to roll my own...

Comment: Am I the only one not beeing able to find any sources at http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphitz ?

Answer (score 2):

Windows does not store historical data, you will need to use a database such as the [tz database](http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm). I couldn't find any Delphi code listed on that particular page, but there might be some floating around. Otherwise, you'll have to port it from one of the languages that *are* currently supported...

Answer (score 0):

How about: [Convert UTC string to TDatetime in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597754/convert-utc-string-to-tdatetime-in-delphi)

Also, there is some discussion and Delphi code for doing this at: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1486209&page=1

And you can find a fair bit on this with a Google search for: [utc local delphi](http://www.google.com/search?q=utc+local+delphi)