# javascript incorrectly determines daylight savings time line -- an example out of 2006

Tags: php, javascript, windows, dst, unix-timestamp

I have read many StackOverflow questions on the javascript `new Date()` object when it comes to daylight savings time *lines* -- as in when they are crossed. However, I haven't seen an answer about this particular problem or a way to work around it while *still relying* on 'unix time'.

I have personally chosen to work around this issue by passing the javascript date as a date to my PHP code rather than the unix time. Yet, the nagging question still remains! I have confirmed this behavior on IE8, Chrome, and FF so I'm assuming it will behave the same for you. (**Update:** OSX users might *not* be able to generate this behavior)

My Research; the closest questions to my issue:

- [This user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018320/javascript-date-objects-and-daylight-savings-time) was working on the particular hours right around the DST change.
- [This user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543580/javascript-time-zones-and-daylight-savings-time) was worried about the presentation of the time depending on the user's time zone. The accepted answer on that page mentioned that `getTimezoneOffset` is "flaky" which led me to not delve into that.
- See my answer below on other questions that have some great insights

I have generated a test scenario around November 1st, 2006. This may or may not work the same for you depending on the time zone you are in. If I understand the javascript aspect correctly, you will need to synchronize your PC's clock to

> Eastern Time (US & Canada) and check the 'Automatically adjust clock for Daylight Saving Time'.

I am basing this experiment off of the "Indianapolis" time zone in PHP. My javascript result, when I find the unix time for November 1st, 2006 is **one hour off** of what the PHP generates (3600 seconds). According to [this page](http://timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=105&syear=2000) (Thanks Jon!) javascript is wrong.

The two languages results' come **back into agreement** on 11/06/2006!

This and other research causes me to believe that Javascript got its history wrong and picked the wrong Sunday to 'Fall back' out of DST -- thereby causing the discrepancy I am seeing.

I have tried to simplify this as much as possible but there are still quite a few gears in motion.

1. [Here is the PHP code and output](http://ideone.com/lSd9C) that shows the CORRECT number of milliseconds until the date 11/01/2006.

   date_default_timezone_set("America/Indiana/Indianapolis");
   echo "Unixtime for November 1, 2006 is: ".strtotime("11/01/2006")."\n";
   echo "Unixtime for November 6, 2006 is: ".strtotime("11/06/2006");

The result is:

```
Unixtime for November 1, 2006 is: 1162357200 (where the disagreement lies)
Unixtime for November 6, 2006 is: 1162789200
```

Both of them are based off of GMT-0500.

2. In Javascript, (see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpZeY/5/)**), I call `new Date` and then `getTime()` upon it like so (and remove the milliseconds):

   new Date("2006/11/01").getTime()/1000
   new Date("2006/11/06").getTime()/1000

This generates the values

```
1162353600 <-- PHP outputs: 1162357200
1162789200 <-- the same as PHP for '2006/11/06'; congruence is restored
```

which is a *difference* (for 2006/11/01) from the output via PHP of 3600 seconds -- or one hour. This value (one hour earlier) when processed in my PHP application generated the prior day (2006/10/31) which was unacceptable since it broke my navigation forward. ([see more explanation of my particular scenario](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3640316#3640316))

Outputting in Javascript: `Date("2006/11/01")` without calling `getTime()` clears up some of the mystery because javascript reveals the offset it was using `GMT-0400`.

My [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpZeY/5/)** experiment (also listed above) shows these results.

**(you may need to change your computer's timezone to see the identical behavior).

Possibly coming into play is that [according to Wikipedia 2006 was the first year that Indiana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_the_United_States#Indiana) began using DST. A curious puzzle either way.

Since I have already worked out my solution (by avoiding relying on unix time in my javascript) I thought I should post this for posterity and hopefully someone might know how to correct the value javascript is showing.

**The question is this:** How does one bring the two 'unix time' results between PHP and javascript into alignment? I would be grateful to learn how around the DST 'line' or in general. (I'm currently assuming the DST line is the problem).

**Update:** an iMac running Chrome generated the results that PHP is generating. What??? Wild. Any javascript-side fix to this behavior looks like it would be a great undertaking (or at least ugly). Perhaps this *is not* a javascript problem since it generates the correct answer depending on the OS (or other factors?).

Notably, on this iMac I **did not** force the timezone and I'm not sure this Apple computer would allow it. The settings for "Set date and time automatically" was checked (`true`) and `disabled`. The time zone was set to Eastern Daylight Time. The box to 'Set timezone automatically' was unchecked (`false`) and `disabled`.

I added the `Windows` tag to highlight that it doesn't seem to be a problem in OSX.

**Update:** According to the site [linked above](http://timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=105&syear=2000), I verified that [all the following dates crossed into a new GMT offset on the appropriate dates (updated fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/xpZeY/7/) -- unlike how the 2006 response was *one week off*. I.e., on November 4th, 2007, it was `GMT-4` and November 5th, 2007, it returned `GMT-5`.

- 2007  Sunday, March 11 at 2:00 AM Sunday, November 4 at 2:00 AM
- 2008  Sunday, March 9 at 2:00 AM  Sunday, November 2 at 2:00 AM
- 2009  Sunday, March 8 at 2:00 AM  Sunday, November 1 at 2:00 AM
- 2010  Sunday, March 14 at 2:00 AM Sunday, November 7 at 2:00 AM
- 2011  Sunday, March 13 at 2:00 AM Sunday, November 6 at 2:00 AM

Lastly, if you know the proper channels to submit this error in 2006 to whatever timezone source Javascript is relying on, please do so and let me know about it.

Comment: That's interesting, but do you have an actual question, otherwise it is likely to be closed as off topic.

Comment: @vascowhite, the question is "How does one bring the two answers out of PHP and javascript into alignment? Either around the DST 'line' or in general"

Comment: Sorry, I must have skipped that bit. Where is it?

Comment: I don't mean to hound you, but you've put a lot of work into this and I'm sure you don't want to see it closed.

Comment: I tweaked it a bit, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, [time in Indiana is very complicated](http://www.mccsc.edu/time.html).

But in this case, I believe Javascript is wrong. The output of your Javascript on my machine (having set the time zone) is "Wed Nov 01 2006 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)" on Chrome and "Wed Nov 1 00:00:00 EDT 2006" on Internet Explorer - but [daylight saving time ended in Indianapolis in 2006 on October 29th](http://timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=105&syear=2000).

.NET's `TimeZoneInfo` class gives the same result:

```
// Ignore the daft ID; it really means Eastern time
var zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var local = new DateTime(2006, 11, 1);
Console.WriteLine(zone.GetUtcOffset(local));
```

Output:

```
-5:00:00
```

(So it knows it's not in daylight saving time then.)

Likewise in Noda Time (my own date and time library, which uses the tzdb database):

```
var zone = DateTimeZone.ForId("America/Indiana/Indianapolis");
var instant = new Instant(1162357200 * NodaConstants.TicksPerSecond);
var zoned = new ZonedDateTime(instant, zone);
Console.WriteLine(zoned);
```

Result:

```
Local: 01/11/2006 00:00:00 Offset: -05 Zone: America/Indiana/Indianapolis
```

Comment: Thank you Jon; these two links are very helpful. I wasn't sure where I could get the official answer on when the time really changed. Do you know how we could bring Javascript back into alignment?

Comment: @veeTrain: I don't know where it's getting its information from, I'm afraid. It's going to depend on the browser and OS, I suspect.

Comment: Wow; thank you so much for your time! You certainly carry a lot of clout around here) I had no idea this would be that difficult to discern. So are you saying that there is no way (that you know of) to find out why Javascript seems to have it wrong -- nor a way to correct for this type of scenario?

Comment: @veeTrain: Not that I know of, I'm afraid. At least, not without going to some web service or other. Bear in mind that time zone databases are frequently updated due to political changes.

Comment: Fascinating! Again, thank you so much for your time. I'll likely grant you what I can if nobody else has any thoughts.

Comment: @veeTrain: If you have any non-Windows machines you can easily try the JS on, I'd be interested to hear what results you get...

Comment: Jon! I literally gasped to discover: An Apple PC nearby generated the **same** Unix timestamp in the jsfiddle I created (1162357200). Then, I tried October 28th which generates `GMT-4` (correct!) whereas October 29th generates `GMT-5`. Great suggestion but now what would you suggest to someone that wants the correct `getTime()`?

Comment: @veeTrain: I assume you meant October 28th in the first case there? As for getting the correct time - tricky. It's more likely to be accurate for *current* dates and times, of course. It really depends on what you're trying to do with the results, I'm afraid - I know that's somewhat woolly, but date and time handling *really* should be done on a case-by-case basis, because if you model it inappropriately, you'll let yourself in for problems :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11069/discussion-between-veetrain-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: @veeTrain: Sorry, chat doesn't really work for the way I interact with SO :(

Comment: I don't think I would if I was you, either :-) Feel free to read the transcript to see my update. What I'm hearing you say is that there is no generic solution to correct these boundary cases aside from possibly getting a JSON request out to PHP to ask what _it_ thought the unixtime was.

Comment: @veeTrain: Yes, that's basically right. If you can't trust the time zone information on the client, you'll have to go somewhere else. (It doesn't have to be JSON of course, and it doesn't have to go to a PHP server... but it'll have to go to *something* that can be trusted.)

Answer (score 0):

Phew; I think Jon has some excellent points and confirmations that Javascript is pulling the wrong database on Windows machines for when the Daylight Savings time began -- at least in Indiana -- in the early weeks of November, 2006.

I still don't know exactly how I would go about solving this dilemma within Javascript. However, since my main problem was the 'incongruency' between Javascript and PHP (after all, if they changed into DST at the same day / the same hour, then I ***never*** would have noticed that there was a problem), the solution is probably to stop relying on one or the other.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5742576/469643), while not retrieving a unixtime, demonstrates how I might go about resolving this tension if I needed to continue relying on unixtime. It's actually a pretty slick solution, IMHO. A brief summary of it: retrieve timezone info via AJAX. This would mean PHP would always agree about the unixtime at 00:00:00 on any particular day since it would be essentially providing the value itself.

However, this still doesn't feel like a real solution to the problem: Javascript is retrieving *an incorrect understanding* of when the Eastern Time Zone exited Daylight Savings Time. I would still appreciate knowing how one would go about correcting for this extremely small and narrow window of inconsistency.

Could it even be as complicated as a 'probably-not-yet-developed' Windows patch since the OSX machine I experimented with output correct values in Javascript?

I doubt that my scenario and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509360/datepicker-date-off-by-one-day) are related, but it is a fascinating bug that I came across while researching. In that question, the Date object -- depending on the format passed -- could generate some really surprising output.

If someone wanted to subvert the reliance on the user's computer's timezone db for calculating the proper date, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3533246/469643) might provide some assistance in cooking up and relying on ones own timezone database. I have not investigated working with that sort of solution nor how to override the unixtime result returned by Javascript but that is the closest answer I have found. I wonder what the overhead would be...? **Be sure to post an answer if you can implement this type of solution** -- that would likely be the true answer to my original question.